# Referencing HTML elements with JavaScript: getElement* after querySelector*

Tags: javascript, html

The task in a JavaScript textbook: find element with the "info[0]" name that's inside the form with the "search-person" name on this [page](http://learn.javascript.ru/task/find-elements/table.html).

My variant of the solution was:

```
document.querySelector('form[name="search-person"]').getElementsByName('info[0]')[0];
```

But every time I run the code in Firefox console the error pops up:

```
TypeError: document.querySelector(...).getElementsByName is not a function
```

The actual answer for the task

```
document.querySelector('form[name="search-person"] [name="info[0]"]');
```

is simpler than mine, but I can't understand why my version provoke the error anyway because my similar code for the previous task - find the first "input" element inside the "search" form - works fine:

```
document.querySelector('form[name="search"]').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` is a method of `document`, not of any `HTML Element` - unlike `getElementsByTagName` which is a method of any `HTML Element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I can't understand why my version provoke the error anyway because
>   my similar code for the previous task

As suggested by the error itself.

[Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element) doesn't have a method `getElementsByName`.

and [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns an element.